# C compile code for ARM with accum data type on x86/x64

Tags: gcc, compilation, arm

I have some code written for ARM that uses the accum data type. I don't know very much about it, but it seems an arm-gcc extension for fixed point numbers.

Is there any way to compile that code for x84/x64 Linux for emulation purposes?

Comment: You could probably implement is as a simple C++ class.

Comment: It's plain C, unfortunately.

Comment: Well you could try compiling it as C++ regardless - it might take a little work to fix any incompatibilities but it could be worth it in the long run if you want emulation.